# How to set a font and size to save information in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to save the extracted data in the same format, Arial font size 12.

Currently the code does not follow a pattern of font and size.

I tried using the utf-8 command and it didn't work.

```
df_conversas = pd.DataFrame({'Nomes': nomes_conversas})

df_conversas.to_excel('conversas.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with an [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) *engine* :

```
df_conversas = pd.DataFrame({"Nomes": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]})

with pd.ExcelWriter("conversas.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df_conversas.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

    workbook = writer.book
    workbook.formats[0].set_font_name("Arial")
    workbook.formats[0].set_font_size(12)
    
    header_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"font_name": "Arial", "font_size": 12, "bold": True}
    )

    writer.sheets["Sheet1"].write(0, 0, "Nomes", header_format)

    #if you have more than a column, use this :
    #for idx, col in enumerate(df_conversas.columns):
    #    writer.sheets["Sheet1"].write(0, idx, col, header_format)
```

Output :

[image]